# Using hover class

Tags: jquery

Using hover class of css.

I have a label called "show" & i have a button. So basically i want to change the background of the button (want the same color of hover) when i hover on the label i.e i want to use  btn:hover {} class which is already there in css.

```
show - > on hover -> addClass - > btn:hover {} to (btn)  

$('.addingAction').hover(function() {
        $('.btnRBlk').css({
            //use hover class

        }};                 
        },function() {

});
```

Comment: Include your HTML and CSS please. The question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: sorry, from your question im confused.

Comment: You can't manipulate CSS pseudo-classes via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this with pure CSS (no jQuery), but you would need to post your HTML.

However, as it is, the easiest way to do this would be to add a class name to your CSS:

```
btn:hover, .hovered {
    /* Styles */
}
```

And then use the jQuery [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods:

```
$('.addingAction').hover(function() {
    $('.btnRBlk').addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
    $('.btnRBlk').removeClass("hovered");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this :

```
$(".addinAction").hover(function(){
    $(".btnRBlk").trigger("mouseenter");
},function(){
    $(".btnRBlk").trigger("mouseleave");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You jquery code has error

```
   $('.addingAction').hover(function() {
            $('.btnRBlk').css({
                //use hover class

            });//this was errorneaous                 
            },function() {

    });
```